# Django precise_bbcode not properly parsing contents of [code] tags?

Tags: python, django, bbcode

I just installed precise_bbcode 1.2.6 in my Django 1.10.4 application.

When I provide the string:

```
>>> s = """
    [code]
    for i in var:
      print(var[i])
    [/code]
    """
```

the output is just plain text:

> for i in var:
>         print(var[i])

However if I change the `[i]` to `[i2]` it works fine and formats the text as expected.

I am guessing that precise_bbcode thinks `[i]` has something to do with italic text (even though it is surrounded by [code] tags and the [i] has no associated closing tag). This behavior is also present for `[b]` and probably any other recognized tag

I then I tried setting the option `render_embedded = False` but I still get the same behavior.

I then tried making my own "code" tag:

```
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter

class PygmentsBBCodeTag(BBCodeTag):
    name = 'code'

    class Options:
        strip = False
        replace_links = False
        render_embedded = False
        transform_newlines = False
        escape_html = False

    def render(self, value, option=None, parent=None):
        print(value)
        return highlight(value, PythonLexer(), HtmlFormatter())

tag_pool.register_tag(PygmentsBBCodeTag)
```

And got the same result.

Stranger still, in my `PygmentsBBCodeTag` class whenever the `[i]` exists I notice that it is never called (as the value is not printed).

Is there any way to tell precise_bbcode to look at the contents between the `[code]` tag purely as a string and to ignore anything except for the closing `[/code]` tag??

Thanks

Comment: You should report it as a bug to the developers.

Comment: I see the author is Morgan Aubert - https://github.com/ellmetha should I contact him? Or is there a better place?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that only requires two lines in `bbcode/parser.py` to be added.

> **Note**: *this worked for my application and based on my testing this
>   change did not create unwanted side effects. I can not guarantee
>   this is the best solution and I encourage that you test your app
>   throughly after making this edit. However, if I do find any undesirable
>   behavior in the future I will try to post the details here.*

---

The procedure:

1. Find the file: `.../dist-packages/precise_bbcode/bbcode/parser.py`
2. Open file and navigate to:

   - For django-precise-bbcode 1.2.6 locate the [line #242](https://coveralls.io/jobs/7352616/source_files/1006261653#L242)
   - For django-precise-bbcode 1.2.9 locate the [line #248](https://github.com/ellmetha/django-precise-bbcode/blob/develop/precise_bbcode/bbcode/parser.py#L248)
3. Then modify the contents:

   From:

   ```
   if previous_tag_options.end_tag_closes:
       opening_tags.pop()
   ```

   To:

   ```
   if not tag_options.render_embedded:
       opening_tags = []    
   elif previous_tag_options.end_tag_closes:
       opening_tags.pop()
   ```

Those are the only changes needed.

After doing this, for any tag where `render_embedded = False` it no longer appears to break when something resembling a bbcode tag is recognized within the enclosed text. And now passes the entire string to be formatted by the syntax highlighter.

[Update]

Nearly a year later (and after upgrading to version 1.2.9) and the original issue remains. However I have been using the procedure as illustrated in this post and so far it still works well!